# In Asp.Net, How do I access the info about caller control of ObjectDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, objectdatasource, private-members

Is it possible to access in Selecting Event of ObjectDataSource:

```
protected void odsProduct_Selecting(object sender, ObjectDataSourceSelectingEventArgs e)
{
    object Control = (((System.Web.UI.DataSourceView)(sender)).Events.head.handler).Target;
}
```

Problem:

> 'System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Events' cannot be used in this context because the get accessor is inaccessibe
>   'System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Events' is inaccessible due to its protection level

In Debugger I can see the Target Control and it's correct values. Any idea?

[image: Debug]

Comment: The sender will tell you who's triggering the event. What are you trying to achieve specifically? Can you provide more context, please?

Comment: The sender is the ObjectDataSource, which does might contain the trigger event, but not the control of the page where the ObjectDateSource was binded. I need to access generic every grid using the ObjectDataSource to get the PageSize, because it's not given in the ObjectDataSource. I almost got it working with reflections.